# How can I improve and un-hold this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Frequent user of stackexchanges but new to the Unix one specifically, so maybe there are different rules here I'm unaware of (I read "how to ask a good question").

My question was put on hold:  ['at' command won't open program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375227/at-command-wont-open-program?noredirect=1#comment668120_375227).  Originally, I foolishly failed to mention my OS, although there is ample evidence in the question I'm using a Mac.  The question was put on hold after I edited that in, though (I believe) and even after flagging it for a moderator, I haven't gotten any response (possible I'm just being impatient).

What is this question missing?  I feel it's clear what I'm asking and what efforts I've put forward so far, but maybe I'm too close to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you've recently deleted the question, so it won't get any answers now.

I was one of the VTC votes when it wasn't clear what the actual problem was -- the python code or the interaction with `at` or opening a GUI interface from `at`. The only indication that you were on a Mac were the email headers, so adding that information was helpful.

After you responded to the comments, I was also one of the votes to reopen; it was reopened after being on-hold for only about 17 hours.

I was also then one of the VTC votes when you indicated that the problem went away; if we can't validate that an Answer works, then the Question doesn't do much good any more -- even if it was a good question!

My only guess as to the lack of answers is a small OSX community here; only ~1% of our total questions are [tagged OSX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx?sort=newest&pageSize=50), and 25% of those are [unanswered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50).

Comment: Definitely understood that the question should have been closed once I could not reproduce the problem, no issues there.  For what it's worth, though, Stack Overflow first sent me here because they said it was an Unix issue.  So where should I have posted it?!?  (and thank you for your ongoing help!)

Comment: It's in-topic here, imho, but you could try Ask Different. I don't know their scope.